# IQueryable<T> and async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, iqueryable

Let's take a very simple example. What is the difference between this:

```
var sublist = Task.WhenAll(list.Select(x => x.getYAsync()));
```

and this:

```
var sublist = Task.WhenAll(list.Select(async x => await x.getYAsync()));
```

In both cases, the type of `sublist` is the same, so the only difference is semantic. Does one perform better than the other? Is one more standard than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only significant difference regards exception propagation.

If `getYAsync` throws an exception which isn't stored in the returned task* the first option would have an exception when calling `Task.WhenAll` while the second option would have the exception stored in the task returned from `Task.WhenAll` which would be thrown when that task is awaited.

Other than that there's the state machine being built in the `async` lambda which has some (very small) overhead.

The first option performs *slightly* better, while the second is more standard than the other.
The safer option is to explicitly state the `async` and `await` but in such a simple case its somewhat redundant.

<sup>* For example: `Task getYAsync() { throw new Exception(); return Task.Delay(1)}`</sup>